# Does browser cache affect text content also?

Tags: browser, browser-cache

From my observation browsers cache css and image files. If changes were made, you need to hit "force" refresh button if you want to see updated version. However I am not able to verify if browsers also cache text content? For example:

If you have a web page with:

```
<body>
    foo
</body>
```

A user visits it, then you change it to:

```
<body>
    bar
</body>
```

Does the user still need to "force" refresh to see updated text content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course browser cache the html pages, incuding the 'text content'.

> Does the user still need to "force" refresh to see updated text content?

The need to force an update completely depends on how your web server is configured.  If a client wants to be sure it has the freshest content then forcing an update may be required, but if cache control is configured on the server in a way that is useful, then this shouldn't normally be required.

Answer (score 0):

You can verify that browsers cache content by opening Dev Tools in popular browsers (accessible through the F12 keyboard shortcut) & watching the Network (this may have slightly different name in each browser) tab or tools like Fiddler or Firebug to monitor HTTP traffic and see how the page and elements within it load.

If a web page has a HTTP status code of [200 (cache) or 304](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1665082/325251), it means it is cached.